# mdm server - read Configuration file in com.apple.configuration.managed Obj-c

Tags: ios, xcode, file, configuration

I'm using "Objective c"

what is: "kConfigurationKey" use too?

what is: "kConfigurationServerURLKey" use too?

i try to get Configuration file from mdm-server.
but i can't read data in my ipad in xcode.

all what i want is send data from mdm-server over to device.
and save Configuration into the device.

here is my plist there ben isntalled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>##CommandUUID##</string>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RequestType</key>
        <string>InstallApplication</string>
        <key>ManifestURL</key>
        <string>##MDM_SERVER_URL##/package/##PACKAGENO##/Manifest.plist</string>
        <key>ChangeManagementState</key>
        <string>Managed</string>
        <key>ManagementFlags</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Options</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NotManaged</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PurchaseMethod</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>Configuration</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DeviceUUID</key>
            <string>##DEVICE_UUID##</string>
            <key>MDMServer</key>
            <string>##MDM_SERVER##</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Inside my Xcode:

```
static NSString * const kConfigurationKey = @"com.apple.configuration.managed";
static NSString * const kConfigurationServerURLKey = @"https://???";

NSDictionary *serverConfig = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:kConfigurationKey]

NSString *serverURLString = serverConfig[kConfigurationServerURLKey];`

NSLog(@"config: %@", serverURLString);
```

It's NSLog say (config: null)

Comment: Hello Frederik, Are you getting answer of it ? Please help me for same

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pice of code you can use:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"NSLanguages"]){

    //List all in NSLanguages!
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NSLanguages"]);

    //Convert into Array !
    NSArray* arrayNames = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NSLanguages"];

    //print sinagle out (array)
    NSLog(@"%@", arrayNames[0]);
}
```

You just  need to change "NSLanguages" out with "com.apple.configuration.managed" 
you convert standardUserDefaults into an array !

and there you have it :)